# Отловить снятие выделения с ячейки

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне надо поймать момент когда с ячейки определенного столбца DataGrid сняли выделение. Какое нужно для этого событие? Боюсь что обычный LostFocus не подойдет, т.к. во первых индекс не узнаешь откуда именно было снято выделение, во вторых мне надо будет в случае неверных данных в ячейке вернуть туда выделение.

Comment: «ячейки определенного столбца» — эээ, а внутри какого контрола?

Comment: И LostFocus — это очень похоже правильный путь для того, чтобы узнать, когда ушёл фокус. Другого пути нет, разумеется. Правьте код обработчика.

Comment: @VladD ой забыл написать DataGrid конечно.

Comment: Если вам нужна валидация, то надо делать что-то такое: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. Низкоуровневые хаки типа проверки фокуса — плохой путь.